# How to compute statistics with date intervals via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to compute some stats (with a MySQL backend) sorted by date and with dynamic intervals (week, month, year).
Here is a little example :

Mysql table : 
tracker_click

```
| ID   | SITE_ID | CREATED_AT          |
| ---- |---------| --------------------|
| 153  | 2       | 2013-07-22 15:43:25 |
| 154  | 2       | 2013-07-25 16:45:46 |
| 2501 | 2       | 2013-09-15 17:45:48 |
```

I want to get the total click number by SITE_ID by week for the last month with one query
And the same thing by month for the last year.

An example of what I want by week for the last month is :

```
| click number   | SITE_ID | BEGIN_DATE           | END_DATE            |
|----------------|---------|----------------------|---------------------|
| 25             |    2    |  2013-07-01 00:00:00 | 2013-07-08 00:00:00 |
| 19             |    2    |  2013-08-09 00:00:00 | 2013-08-16 00:00:00 |
| 53             |    2    |  2013-0717- 00:00:00 | 2013-08-24 00:00:00 |
```

I don’t know if there is a solution to get exaclty this array with only one query without any other processes.

Thank you

Comment: To do this, assuming you want months listed where the count is zero, generate a list of the time periods you require and then left join you data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the counts for the last month (ie, last 4 weeks), including weeks where the count is 0 for each site id. If you have a table of sites to get the site id from it means the cross join to the sub query can be replaced with a simple cross join to a table.

This generates a range of numbers from 0 to 5 and subtracts that number of weeks from the current date, formats that to give the Sunday and Saturday of the resulting week and checks that the resuling week is a week between the current date and the current date minus 1 month (done this way rather that just subtracting 4 weeks to cope with variable length months).

```
SELECT Weeks.aWeek_start, Weeks.aWeek_end, all_site_id.site_id, COUNT(tracker_click.id)
FROM
(
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i WEEK), '%Y%U Sunday 00:00:00'), '%X%V %W %H:%i:%s') AS aWeek_start,
            STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i WEEK), '%Y%U Saturday 23:59:59'), '%X%V %W %H:%i:%s') AS aWeek_end
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5)units
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i WEEK), '%Y%U') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y%U') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%U')
) Weeks
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT site_id
    FROM tracker_click
) AS all_site_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tracker_click
ON tracker_click.CREATED_AT BETWEEN Weeks.aWeek_start AND Weeks.aWeek_end
AND tracker_click.site_id = all_site_id.site_id
GROUP BY Weeks.aWeek_start, Weeks.aWeek_end, all_site_id.site_id
```

A similar query could be done for months of the year

```
SELECT Months.aMonth_start, Months.aMonth_end, all_site_id.site_id, COUNT(tracker_click.id)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i MONTH), '%Y/%m/01 00:00:00') AS aMonth_start,
            DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL units.i MONTH)), '%Y/%m/%d 23:59:59') AS aMonth_end
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11)units
) Months
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT site_id
    FROM tracker_click
) AS all_site_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tracker_click
ON tracker_click.CREATED_AT BETWEEN Months.aMonth_start AND Months.aMonth_end
AND tracker_click.site_id = all_site_id.site_id
GROUP BY Months.aMonth_start, Months.aMonth_end, all_site_id.site_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kickstart,
I have the correct row number, the dates are also correct but the tracker count is not ok, 
each row give me a wrong count of click. 

I’ve got only one row in my table for site 954 the tracker_count should be always 0 except for the last row (1)

Comment: It seems that “count(tracker_click_id)” counts each time all rows not only the rows between each dates

Comment: I can't see an error with it (although I could be missing something). Could you set up the tables and a small amount of data on SQL fiddle to demonstrate it please?

Comment: Thankyou again for your help Kickstart, 
you can find an sample here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b9631/5
I’ve had a where clause (line 16) in order to have a result just for one site, but no matter the site_id the query return the same amount of click. this query is quite complicated and I am not the best at SQL, maybe this work fine but i’am not adding the correct where clause...
the where clause => "WHERE all_site_id.site_id = 813"

Comment: Ah, seen the problem. The ON clause for the LEFT OUTER JOIN should also join on the site_id. I have amended the answer above to correct this missing bit. Hopefully that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*), site_id, extract(WEEK from created_at) as start_date, 
date_add(extract(WEEK from created_at), 1, week) as end_date
FROM click_tracker
GROUP BY site_id, extract(WEEK from created_at)
```

and you can add where clause to filter results additionally.